# Osgi Config ManagedService Dictionary keys case insensitive

Tags: osgi, aem, apache-felix

I am running into an issue. I have a `org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService` impl client for an osgi configuration. The configuration is a collection of key-value pairs.
The keys in these properties, when passed to the updated method(`ManagedService.updated`) of the `ManagedService` as a `java.util.Dictionary` object seem to be case insensitive i.e. `props.get("HellO")` works even though the key in the config is "Hello".

When I convert that dictionary to a `Hashmap` by iterating over its entries, the keys in the map become case sensitive as expected. Is this expected that the keys in `Dictionary` are case insensitive?

This was tested on an AEM 6.2 instance.

Here is my `ManagedService` impl class.

```
public class ConfigService implements ManagedService {

public void updated(final Dictionary props) throws ConfigurationException {
    // props.get("HellO") returns value
    if (props != null) {
        String pid = (String) props.get(Constants.SERVICE_PID);
        // convert to map
        Map map = map(props);
        // map.get("HellO") returns null
        // map.get("Hello") returns value
    }
}

private static Map map(Dictionary dict) {
    Map map = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    for (Enumeration keys = dict.keys(); keys.hasMoreElements();) {
        Object key = keys.nextElement();
        map.put(key, dict.get(key));
    }
    return map;
}
```

The `ManagedService` impl is registered as a service using the below code.

```
final Dictionary props = new Hashtable();
props.put(Constants.SERVICE_PID, "pid.of.the.osgi.configuration" );
ServiceRegistration configSvc = context.registerService(ManagedService.class.getName(),
                new ConfigService(), props);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as per the Configuration Admin Service specification.

> > The name or key of a property must always be a String object, and is not
> >     case-sensitive during look up, but must preserve the original case.

Apache felix source code for reference.
https://github.com/apache/felix/blob/trunk/configadmin/src/main/java/org/apache/felix/cm/impl/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.java

> > /**
> >      * The `CaseInsensitiveDictionary` is a
> >      * `java.util.Dictionary` which conforms to the requirements laid
> >      * out by the Configuration Admin Service Specification requiring the property
> >      * names to keep case but to ignore case when accessing the properties.
> >      */

Comment: The reason that the keys are case insensitive is that at the time (2000) it looks like X.500 specs were going to be important. X.509 certificates, SNMP, and LDAP are I guess the few things left. Case sensitive became standard and we were stuck with a bad decisions. One of the disadvantages of a standard that goes out of its way to be backward compatible.